# Laptop shutdown when when using windows apps

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have been using my laptop for 4years. But this problem has never occurred until I upgraded its OS to Windows 10 recently. I have been playing asphalt8 game for more than a year now. But this problem has never occurred.

Recently I've installed Age of empires: castle siege game and Asphalt8: airborne  after upgrading  it to windows 10. My laptop is shutting down  whenever I use these apps. It doesn't shutdown as long as I'm not using these apps.

**It only shut down (as in plugging off a PC) when using AOE: CS and Asphalt8**

I couldn't figure out what the problem is either motherboard or driver failure or anything else.

> Graphics
>   [image: Graphics Info.]
>
> CPU Info.
>   [image: CPU Info.]
>
> Motherboard info.
>   [image]

Comment: Shutting down as in showing you the "Shutting down" screen, showing a blue screen of death (with `:(` and a message) or something else?

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer? You say "when I use these apps". So, does that mean they run for a period of time before the shutdown? Or do they shutdown as the program is loading? Have you installed the latest drivers for your laptop and all Windows updates?

Comment: Also, do you have up to date graphics drivers installed, and what is your graphics card?

Comment: Prime suspect would be dust bunnies causing overheat. When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned?

Comment: @RowlandShaw There are no external graphics only intel graphics. and also not showing just switch off (no blue screen).

Comment: @CharlieRB yes, I have checked event viewer, it shows nothing but "app stopped responding".

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm sure it is not because of overheating.Even though I cleaned it like a week ago, This problem still persists.

Comment: Is it just theses two games or do other games cause this problem?

Comment: Yes, These two only, I'm afraid this problem might damage the hard disk.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling these games?

Comment: Update your question to include the Intel driver information.  This problem is not caused by damage to the HDD.

Comment: 75 degrees Celsius is sort of warm.  Is that at load or just idle?  You have a driver problem, Intel has not released a Windows 10 display driver, and I don't believe the `HD Graphics 3000` driver released for other products will work in your case.  You can try it, unless you install display drivers, you won't be able to run those applications.

Comment: Opera Browser is running for about 4-5 hours now.

Comment: @saichaitanya - If you are only running a browser, then your hardware is running really warm, the restarts are likely caused by it simply overheating.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed in the screenshots is the really high CPU temperature - on my laptop with i3-2xxxM the temperature never exceeds 60°C even under load, and idle temps are usually about 40°C in normal room temperature conditions. If these are screenshots from the idle system then this would be a good reason for an emergency shutdown when you start a game that uses a lot of processor power.

There could be just a lot of dust in the cooling system so it's probably worth trying to use a vacuum cleaner and suck the dust out of the laptop (in opposite direction to the airflow when the machine is switched on). But make sure by all means that the PC is completely off and carefully block the CPU fan with a plastic pin or something like that when you use the vacuum cleaner as it may make the fan spin so fast that it's bearing gets damaged otherwise. This is a good idea from time to time anyway, but always remember to block the fan.

Then you should try playing with the energy options in control panel, for example there are settings for "active" or "silent" cooling policies. It may also make sense to look for any tools or customized drivers on the PC manufacturer's website. Sometimes, although less likely on laptops, there are system cooling or temperature management options in the PC's BIOS/UEFI setup, so look if there are any BIOS updates available as well while you're there.

It's still possible that there is a general problem with the Windows 10 chipset drivers and your specific computer mainboard, as these drivers control the system cooling and fan behaviour, but I wouldn't give up so quickly. But in general, this sounds like a heat problem to me.

Answer (score -1):

So, as it is just these two games that are causing problems, I highly doubt it is a Motherboard or Drive failure. It could be that Windows 10 is just being the difficult system we all know it is... I have had a few games that worked on previous versions of Windows not just stop working in Windows 10, but throw weird errors... This could be happening to you.

So my two-cents: **This is a Software/Windows problem NOT a hardware problem.**
 You sadly might have to give up on those games or find a way to emulate an older windows system in your current one.

However, it could be your graphics drivers are out of date, you should check that too.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Its physically not possible for Windows 10 to be missing DirectX, DirectX 12 is built into Windows 10, the application in question, are not (and cannot be) DX9 applications.

Comment: @Ramhound I forgot about that. I have edited my answer and removed the Direct X part. Thanks.